# How to Pause Swing in Java?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, keypress

- I have a main java program named MainProgram.java
- MainProgram.java has its member as a JFrame MyFrame
- The frame MyFrame has a JPanel in it called MyPanel
- I have overriden the PaintComponent of MyPanel to draw an image.

MainProgram.java constantly gets a feed from a video file and calls the paintComponent of MyPanel.

What I want to do is for the program to wait until I press Enter key. Only when I press the Enter key, should the next frame be taken from the video and displayed.

1. Thread.sleep I saw in so many places cannot be used since, then it cannot listen for key
   press.
2. A Timer cannot be used since I am not timing anything.

The dirty workaround I used was

```
boolean x = false;
.
.
.
while(x==false);
.
.
.
onKeyPressed()
{
    x=true;
    //get frame from video
    //call paintComponent
    x=false;
}
```

Anyone can give a good solution please?

Comment: Kindly, I beg you to give me a suggestion before downvoting. You know people are willing to modify their questions. A cold downvote?

Comment: In the action listener of the JButton, which is tied to the Enter key, you get the image from the video and pass it to MyPanel with a setImage method.  Then, you repaint MyPanel.  Otherwise, MyPanel keeps redrawing the image you last passed to MyPanel through setImage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to collect each image frame in your implementation of `doInBackground()`, `publish()` frames as they become available, and add them to a `List<BufferedImage>` on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) in your implementation of `process()`. You can navigate through the  `List<BufferedImage>` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20116944/230513) for `List<String>`.