# Iterating through array list in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist, iteration

I have an `ArrayList` which holds employee record details from data inputted into `JTextFields`. I have displayed this with a `showMessageDialog` box to confirm that they are being added to the list correctly.

The employees are created and added to the list correctly but how do I cycle through the `ArrayList` one record at a time and have the information displayed in the `JTextFields`?

Edited as below:

I don't think I have asked the question properly. I have a button that enables me to show the contents of the first element of my array list to the GUI. See below:

`nField.setText(nameList.get(0).getName());`
`bField.setText(nameList.get(0).getBirth());`
`jField.setText(nameList.get(0).getID());`

What I need is something to show the next element.

I have a list iterator that I am trying to use but I simply can’t get it to work.

I have tried this but it results in the last element being shown:

`for (int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++) {`

`nameList.get(i);`

`nField.setText(nameList.get(i).getName());`
`bField.setText(nameList.get(i).getBirth());`
`jfield.setText(nameList.get(i).getID()); }`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: can u post some code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*GUI in java “go to previous/next” option*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20112159/230513).

Comment: Code posted and question edited. @trashgod - It appears similar but I can't fix my issue from the answer to that question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different options, but the short of it is, you'll have to tie your employee record to the JTextField somehow. One way to do this is by creating a simple object to hold the relation:

```
public class EmployeeRecordToJTextfield {
  private EmployeeRecord employeeRecord;
  private JTextField jTextField;

  public EmployeeRecordToJTextfield(EmployeeRecord employeeRecord, JTextField jTextField) {
    this.employeeRecord = employeeRecord;
    this.jTextField = jTextField;
  }

  public EmployeeRecord getEmployeeRecord() {
    return employeeRecord;
  }

  public JTextField getJTextField() {
    return jTextField;
  }
}
```

Instead of the `EmployeeRecord`, you stick instances of this class in the list:

```
List<EmployeeRecordToJTextfield> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new EmployeeRecordToJTextfield(employeeRecord, jTextField));
```

When you iterate over this list, you can transfer the data you choose:

```
for (EmployeeRecordToJTextfield e : list) {
  JTextField textField = e.getJTextField();
  EmployeeRecord record = e.getEmployeeRecord();
  textField.setText(record.getName());
}
```

Another option, maybe simpler, is by converting your list to a map and map EmployeeRecords to their JTextField.

**Update based on the Question update**

I hope I now understand what you're asking, but if so, I'd just do this:

Store the index of the 'current' shown item in a variable or hidden GUI field.

```
private int currentIndex = 0; // Start with the first item.
```

When you want to show the next item (perhaps through a Next or Previous button), get the next value. Compensate for list length:

```
int nextIndex = currentIndex+1;
if (nextIndex >= nameList.size()) nextIndex = 0;
if (nextIndex < 0) nextIndex = nameList.size()-1;
```

Now you can use nextIndex to fetch the correct entry from your list:

```
nField.setText(nameList.get(nextIndex).getName());
bField.setText(nameList.get(nextIndex).getBirth()); 
jfield.setText(nameList.get(nextIndex).getID());
```

And don't forget to update the currentIndex:

```
this.currentIndex = nextIndex;
```

Comment: I very much appreciate your reply but I think I over complicated the question. I have edited my question and included source code.

Comment: @JavaNewbie I updated the answer, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Perfect, thank you Ricardo. This has really helped. It even goes back to the first record after the final record. I have used the same code for the previous button but used `currentIndex-1`. This works until you get to the first record. It then breaks down when you try to go to the previous record. What am I missing?

Comment: @JavaNewbie You'd have to add a line to cover for when you're on the first element: `if (nextIndex < 0) nextIndex = nameList.size()-1;`

Comment: Can't thank you enough. Been struggling with this for a while and can finally move on to other aspects. You are a credit to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Use `for` loop:

```
for(JTextField a : your_list){
    do_something();
}
```